# flowtype- string is incompatible with null

Tags: flowtype

Flow is telling me that an explicitly passed-in string is incompatible with null, and it seems to have something to do with an exploded object also being passed in.

I have the following in my react bootstrap library interface definition file:

```
declare export type FormControlProps = {|
  componentClass?: ?componentClass,
  // componentClass is an enum of strings 'select' | 'div' etc
  // There are other params here, too.
|}
```

And the following in a component:

```
import { FormControl, type FormControlProps } from 'react-bootstrap';

type EnumSelectProps = {|
  defaultText: string,
  ...FormControlProps,
|};

// and in the render method:
  const { defaultText, ...other: FormControlProps } = this.props;

  <FormControl
    {...other}
    componentClass="select"
    value={this.state.value}
    onChange={event => this.onChange(event.target.value)}
  >
    { children }
  </FormControl>
```

This seems to be fine, right? `...other` has the type `FormControlProps`. However, I get the complaint:

```
           v-----------
 43:       <FormControl
 44:         {...other}
 45:         componentClass="select"
...:
 48:       >
           ^ props of React element `FormControl`
 45:         componentClass="select"
                            ^^^^^^^^ string. This type is incompatible with
463:     componentClass?: ?componentClass,
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ null. See lib: flow-typed/npm/react-bootstrap_v0.x.x.js:463
```

What gives? If I cast `other` as `any` (i.e.`...(other: any)`), it works. Also, if I make `componentClass` only left-hand-side optional `componentClass?: componentClass`, it works. (That's not the correct definition, though.) Is there any less-hacky way to handle this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This should work in `flow v0.56.0` as you can see on [flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoALgTwA4FMwDGcAttnAHa7noDCMAhgM6NgC8YA5I7jLgehzAAfTgBMAlgDcOAbgw58AMTgAnYjQroVcGAAVt2FuwDeQ1GEIkylanSaMA-AC4wDoqQpVaDZgBpUQgC+qKjiHiroYABKuPT8YFDaxJwqsfyyoeGRWHhgxgBycKK4gQlJKWkCcmFkEXlgymoa1NowYKWJJBVx6AC0AEZwcOiMWvTYGfK5AKLkAK7EAMo8fOj6cIZseWYWBAAW4jCiqeQuhcX+FsVQ9HMw6AAquAAe6C6jKuLkAOaXYAB0gMa6k0rXWhn8QTkOXwswWy14-EW6Ho6HwJnMYEk9Bgc1w7y0X1+qGCqGAwDA9HIojAXzA6D2+BOxRUYGIuAZRSc5gIPhYAFlMBoPDZIi80dSWDEev9hdYvAAeOFLFb8cGMXxgZUI1bI1G4AB8xkxlnIHzm-FUAAoAJTGiwOxhzPAqW1yB0WE0WBniRj-Ub6rb2j0WbG4-GcDh-B2Bd0WYIOig0PZU77osBWsN4gmfH421hG2Mmk3M3Cum1nIr4YNgACQRDNkWMhAORxOmuut3uT1emsB-2GjJULmBzS0OnV7S2Pr92AMjDkXtS6DmKnIGa9FgVo9BOk3DuM-cHZYTId2Vk8tj5rAARNxEegb-vQzi8axjDP-Si0f8syVn2ASYpj8uDvrgkheGwBr0gcfpAamuBWuBXj-CiKhpugv6vrgNqnmeBoAc2+yHMcVDtPuCrADuLQ6ARHo2nGCaBEAA)